# How to force a git checkout revision in Magit if there are unstaged changes?

Tags: magit, git

On the terminal, in a repository with unstaged changes, I can do:

```bash
~/projects/introduction-to-clojure$ git checkout -f 3.7
Branch '3.7' set up to track remote branch '3.7' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch '3.7'
```

The flag `-f` makes the command be a forced checkout, ignoring the unstaged changes.

I wish to achieve the same in Magit. Thus, I do: `magit-status` (`C-x g`), then `magit-branch` (`b`), `branch/revision` (`b`), and, finally, I pick `3.7`.

However, it does not work and the following error message is provided:

```lisp
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    src/introduction_to_clojure/core.clj
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
```

Is it possible to force checkout to a tag in Magit even with unstaged changes? How to do so?

Comment: I'm not aware of any direct way to put the -f flag on branch command, and changing transient level doesn't add it as option. Anyway you always can type the command directlty using Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a hard reset first, if you want to discard the changes. M-x magit-reset-hard (X h)
You can also do what is suggested, i.e. commit or stash.